# Copy texts which is the closest to the target in Vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on buttons to copy texts.
However, I have no idea how to copy each text by using click function with "this", which is like $(this) in Jquery. It must be Vanilla.js
The number of the buttons will be variable in php. 
At this time, those buttons only copy test1 text...
Please give me any advice. Thanks.

```js
var copyEmailBtnSku = document.querySelector('.js-copybtn-sku');
      copyEmailBtnSku.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         var copyTextSku = document.querySelector('.js-copytext-sku');
         var rangeSku = document.createRange();
         rangeSku.selectNode(copyTextSku);
         window.getSelection().addRange(rangeSku);
         try {
            var successfulSku = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msgSku = successfulSku ? 'successfulSku' : 'unsuccessfulSku';
            console.log('Copy command was ' + msgSku);

         } catch(err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
         }
         window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      });
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy test1</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy test2</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test2</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy test3</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

1. You will need to use `document.querySelectorAll('.js-copybtn-sku')` instead of `document.querySelector('.js-copybtn-sku')` as there are multiple elements with same class.
2. Then you will need to loop through the node list collection and bind click event listener to each of them like:

   ```
   var copyEmailBtnSkus = document.querySelectorAll('.js-copybtn-sku');
   copyEmailBtnSkus.forEach(function(btn) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   ```
3. Then to get `.js-copytext-sku` element inside each click you can simply use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) like `this.nextElementSibling`.

```js
var copyEmailBtnSkus = document.querySelectorAll('.js-copybtn-sku');
copyEmailBtnSkus.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var copyTextSku = this.nextElementSibling;
    var rangeSku = document.createRange();
    rangeSku.selectNode(copyTextSku);
    window.getSelection().addRange(rangeSku);
    try {
      var successfulSku = document.execCommand('copy');
      var msgSku = successfulSku ? 'successfulSku' : 'unsuccessfulSku';
      console.log('Copy command was ' + msgSku);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  });
})
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy test1</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy test2</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test2</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy test3</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple working example, You need add class name to your div tag to work properly.

happy coding .

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("sku");

function myFunction() {
  span = this.getElementsByClassName("js-copytext-sku");
  console.log(span[0].innerText);
  
  // after thet, use the fisrt span as copyTextSku
  var copyTextSku = span[0];
  var rangeSku = document.createRange();
  rangeSku.selectNode(copyTextSku);
  window.getSelection().addRange(rangeSku);
  try {
    var successfulSku = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msgSku = successfulSku ? 'successfulSku' : 'unsuccessfulSku';
    console.log('Copy command was ' + msgSku);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<div class="sku">
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy sku</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test1</span>
</div>
<div class="sku">
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy sku</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test2</span>
</div>
<div class="sku">
  <button class="js-copybtn-sku copy-btn">Copy sku</button>
  <span class="js-copytext-sku">test3</span>
</div>
```